# why does printf() gives random output when it should be 0?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, c99

so as printf() is a function and it returns the number of characters written if successful or negative value if an error occurred, looking at this example, the output as expected is **zero**.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(void) 
{     
printf("%d");    
return 0;
}
```

now when I add some more of these **%d** :   http://ideone.com/brw5vG
the output changes to this:
 **0 134513819 -1216430092 134513808**

I am not able to figure out whats up with the random garbage values? There is a negative value here in the output as well, and a negative value justifies an error, so can anyone pinpoint what is the error here exactly? 
Please be concise and specific. Thanks.

Comment: You never actually check the return value of `printf`.

Comment: There's a huge difference between the `printf`'s return value and what it should write to stdout. Two completely different things.

Comment: @remyabel:  That's not the problem here.

Comment: @John I know, I was just pointing it out.

Comment: @remyabel: Nobody does, and I can't think of any implementation where that would serve a purpose here.

Comment: Most modern compilers will emit a warning for this code.

Comment: Are you getting the sense that you're evoking Undefined Behavior yet? :)

Comment: @Dietrich Indeed checking the return value of printf would not solve anything, but OP seems to conflate the return value of printf with his strange output. I'm saying (in tandem with Paulo Bu's comment) that it's orthogonal to the issue because he's not even checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mis-specifiying the format string to `printf` this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and you should have no expectations as to the result. By specifying `%d` you are telling `printf` to expect an `int` argument which you have not provided.

If we look at the C99 draft standard section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which also covers `pritnf` with respect to format specifiers says:

> [...]If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.[...]

Comment: ok, I get it but why are we getting a zero in the first place? I mean if it's an "undefined behaviour" then the first one should also be some random value.

Comment: Undefined means behavior is not defined. Anything could happen.

Answer (score 5):

Because `"%d"` means an integer is expected. You don't pass any, so you get undefined behaviour.

Note that g++ 4.8.2 gives a useful warning:

> warning: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]

similarly for clang++ 3.4:

> warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]

Comment: I don't expect that `printf()` would return an error result here.  Not that it couldn't, it's just that no existing implementation would.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Agreed, undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

*the output as expected is zero*

```
printf("%d");
```

You should not expect anything as your program invokes undefined behavior.

> (C99, 7.19.6.1p2) "[...] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.[...]"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you pose the question; you assume it "should be 0." The fact is that this is undefined behavior, and `printf` will substitute for `%d` whatever happens to be in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes **undefined behavior**. Anything could be happen.

The *C11* Standard says in section `7.21.6` *Formatted input/output functions*:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

You are passing no argument for the corresponding `%d` specifier.

Comment: but why are we getting a zero for the first one?

Comment: @SyedAmeedul: Undefined behaviour means *anything can happen*. Having a zero printed is one example of *anything happening*. Asking "why" is pointless.

Comment: As I said already in case of UB anything could happen. There is no guarantee that the first place always have the value `0`. The result may vary compiler to compiler or even vary on different versions of same compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues at hand: First is why doesn't the compiler issue an error about this bad call to `printf()`, and second is why you get garbage output. I'll answer them one at a time.

`printf()` is a tricky function. While most functions have a constant amount of arguments passed to them, `printf()` is different.
For example, if we take this simple function:

```
int max(int a, int b) {
  if (a > b) return a;
  else return b;
}
```

You can see that this function always receives 2 arguments. This is also something that the compiler knows, and enforces when you compile you code. This is why a call such as `max(4)` won't work. The compiler will see that we are passing `max()` 1 argument instead of 2 and it will issue an error.

`printf()` is a function that takes a variable amount of arguments, and this amount is determined by the amount of format specifiers (things that start with %) in the format string. This means that the compiler cannot know at compile time if the amount of arguments that you passed to printf is enough (or maybe too much).

The reason that you get garbage printed is because of how functions read their input arguments. All input arguments for a function reside on the stack. These are pushed into the stack before the function is called and later addressed by the function. In this case, `printf()` expects to have an extra argument besides the format string (because of the `%d`), and so it looks in the address where its 2nd argument might have been. Alas, that argument wasn't passed, so it will actually look into a place in the stack that might contain anything else (a return address, a frame pointer, a local variable of an enclosing scope or other).

You can read more about how function calls work [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/understanding-stack-frame-of-function-call-in-c-c).

Comment: *This means that the compiler cannot know at compile time if the amount of arguments that you passed to printf is enough* This is wrong. When the format string is a string literal, like in OP example, what does prevent the compiler to know the number of trailing arguments is not correct?

Comment: When the format string is a literal is a special case when the compiler knows that. However, in the general case it can't know.